# Points of compact metric spaces always have a neighborhood contained in one of the covering sets.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

[image]

I'm afraid that I might not understand this question very well. I'm probably oversimplifying things, but assuming the contrary holds, i.e. $\forall \ \epsilon >0$, $\exists \ x \in X$ such that $\forall \ i \in I$, $U_\epsilon(x) \nsubseteq U_i$, then wouldn't a $y \in (U_\epsilon(x) \setminus U_i)$ not be covered by the family $U_i$, hence a contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is not valid. In order that you can arrive at a contradiction you must have a a $y$ such that $ y \in U_{\epsilon} (x)\setminus U_i$ for every $i$ but there is no such $y$. For a correct proof see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_number_lemma

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've read and understood the proof in the link. However I still have trouble understanding why the idea I put forward above doesn't work. My point is precisely that such $y$ cannot exist, since otherwise it would cause a contradiction.

Comment: @ensbana If $U_{\epsilon} (x)$ is not a subset if $U_i$ for any $i$ you can only say there exists $y_i \in  U_{\epsilon} (x) \setminus U_i$. You cannot get one $y$ independent of $i$.

Comment: I'd like to ask one more question. The version of the lemma in my question is slightly different from the one in the wikipedia link, in that the former requires a neighborhood $U_\epsilon(x)$ of $x$ to be in one of the $U_i$'s, whereas the latter requires only a subset of $X$ of diameter less than $\epsilon$. In the proof there's this case where one of the $U_i$'s contains the whole $X$. In this scenario, if $x$ is a point on the boundary of $X$, wouldn't that make $\epsilon = 0$ in the former case?

Comment: The diameter of a ball of radius $\epsilon$ is at most $ 2 \epsilon$. Just change $\epsilon$ to $\epsilon /2$ in the Wikipedia link and you will get your result.

Answer (score 1):

You correcty negated the statement of the existence of $\varepsilon$ to

$$\forall \varepsilon>0 \exists x \in X: \forall i \in I: \exists p\in X: p \in U_\varepsilon(x) \land p \notin U_i$$

(where $p$ is the non-inclusion "witness")

But as should be clear from this, $p$ depends on $\varepsilon$ and $i$; there is not necessarily a single $p$ that works for all of them. But this is what your supposed $y$ would be....